# Cancelling a thread that has a mutex locked does not unlock the mutex

Tags: c++, linux, mutex

helping a client out with an issue that they are having.  I'm more of a sysadmin/DBA guy so I'm struggling with helping them out.  They are saying it is a bug in the kernel/environment, I'm trying to either prove or disprove that before I insist that it is in their code or seek vendor support for the OS.

Happens on Red Hat and Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.7 (and 5.8), application is written in C++

The problem they are experiencing is that the main thread starts a separate thread to do a potentially long-running TCP connect() [client connecting to server].
If the 'long-running' aspect takes too long, they cancel the thread and start another one.

This is done because we don't know the state of the server program:

- server program up and running --> connection immediately accepted
- server program not running, machine and network OK --> connection
  immediately failed with error 'connection refused'
- machine or network crashed or down --> connection takes a long time
  to fail with error 'no route to host'

The problem is that cancelling the thread that has the mutex locked
(with cleanup handlers set up to unlock the mutex) sometimes does NOT unlock the mutex.

That leaves the main thread hung on trying to lock the mutex.

Detailed environment info:

- glibc-2.5-65
- glibc-2.5-65
- libcap-1.10-26
- kernel-debug-2.6.18-274.el5
- glibc-headers-2.5-65
- glibc-common-2.5-65
- libcap-1.10-26
- kernel-doc-2.6.18-274.el5
- kernel-2.6.18-274.el5
- kernel-headers-2.6.18-274.el5
- glibc-devel-2.5-65

Code was built with:
c++ -g3 tst2.C -lpthread -o tst2

Any advice and guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you canceling the thread with the mutex? If you simply kill the thread, there is a good chance the destructor (where I assume the mutex gets unlocked) will never run.

Comment: Most of the time someone says the OS has a bug but their application doesn't, their application does. It's a self-fulfilling prophecy brought on by that kind of thinking: bad thinking, bad code. If they really are just killing the thread dead cold then of course the mutex won't be freed, no code will run to do so. That's their own design issue.

Comment: IIRC, for pthreads, anyway, cancelling a thread in itself will never release locks or other resources held by that thread - the thread must be written to deal with cancellation at specific points and deal with necessary cleanup before it goes away...

Comment: Assuming you're cancelling the thread with pthread_cancel(), you have to make sure every code path possible properly guards mutexes and other resources with pthread_cleanup_push()/pthread_cleanup_pop() and properly cleaning up. With complicated code, it's easy to mess up this one place or another(even more so if you mix in unix signals here) If the code really is 100% solid regarding this, we'd really have to see code that can reproduce this.

Comment: posing some relevant code would help, especially showing how the thread is canceled and how it handles cancelation.

Comment: One possibility might be to get the main thread to close the socket, rather than cancelling the thread. This would cause `connect(...)` in the other thread to fail with `EBADF`, which could be detected and handled appropriately.

Comment: which compiler?  Presumably RHEL's gcc 4.4.4 system compiler?

Comment: "If a mechanic dies in the middle of servicing an airplane, how can we automatically return that airplane into service?" Isn't it obvious that you just **don't do that**. Why cancel the thread anyway? It's not doing any harm is it?

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, this has been a great learning experience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's correct that cancelled threads do not unlock mutexes they hold, you need to arrange for that to happen manually, which can be tricky as you need to be very careful to use the right cleanup handlers around every possible cancellation point.  Assuming you're using `pthread_cancel` to cancel the thread and setting cleanup handlers with `pthread_cleanup_push` to unlock the mutexes, there are a couple of alternatives you could try which might be simpler to get right and so may be more reliable.

Using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to unlock the mutex *will* be more reliable. On GNU/Linux `pthread_cancel` is implemented with a special exception of type `__cxxabi::__forced_unwind`, so when a thread is cancelled an exception is thrown and the stack is unwound. If a mutex is locked by an RAII type then its destructor will be guaranteed to run if the stack is unwound by a `__forced_unwind` exception.  [`Boost Thread`](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/) provides a portable C++ library that wraps Pthreads and is much easier to use. It provides an RAII type `boost::mutex` and other useful abstractions. Boost Thread also provides its own "thread interruption" mechanism which is similar to Pthread cancellation but not the same, and Pthread cancellation points (such as `connect`) are not Boost Thread interruption points, which can be helpful for some applications. However in your client's case since the point of cancellation is to interrupt the `connect` call they probably do want to stick with Pthread cancellation. The (non-portable) way GNU/Linux implements cancellation as an exception means it will work well with `boost::mutex`.

There is really no excuse for explicitly locking and unlocking mutexes when you're writing in C++, IMHO the **most important and most useful** feature of C++ is destructors which are ideal for automatically releasing resources such as mutex locks.

Another option would be to use a robust mutex, which is created by calling [`pthread_mutexattr_setrobust`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html) on a `pthread_mutexattr_t` before initializing the mutex. If a thread dies while holding a robust mutex the kernel will make a note of it so that the next thread which tries to lock the mutex gets the special error code `EOWNERDEAD`. If possible, the new thread can make the data protected by the thread consistent again and take ownership of the mutex.  This is much harder to use correctly than simply using an RAII type to lock and unlock the mutex.

A completely different approach would be to decide if you really need to hold the mutex lock while calling `connect`. Holding mutexes during slow operations is not a good idea. Can't you call `connect` then if successful lock the mutex and update whatever shared data is being protected by the mutex?

My preference would be to both use Boost Thread and avoid holding the mutex for long periods.

Comment: Yes, RAII will more reliably unlock locks. Whether that's desirable is another matter; the lock protects access to objects that are potentially in inconsistent states, and unlocking that lock should only be done when the protected objects are known to be in consistent states. It's not self-evident that automatically unlocking locks when an exception goes by is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Pete, very good point. Unlocking mutexes is not sufficient to make the program correct. Destructors (and RAII) can potentially also be used to leave the data in a safe state, but thanks for drawing attention to the fact that my answer is incomplete (edits welcome btw!) and that thread cancellation in C++ (especially via exceptions) is a thorny subject with no consensus on the right way to do it or deal with it.

Comment: Does `__cxxabi::__forced_unwind` behave entirely as a normal exception (except that it gets magically thrown)? For example would code like `/* save state to be restored */ try { /* do transaction which transiently involves inconsistent state */ } catch (...) { /* rollback to known good state */ throw; }` be properly transactional in the face of thread cancellation? And how does this implementation of cancellation work with `noexcept`? Is it wrong to write code that takes advantage of 'proofs' that exceptions can't be thrown by a certain area of code?

Comment: @bames53, yes, that would work fine. It works like other exceptions except that it can be thrown at any thread cancellation point (which basically means POSIX cancellation points are not `noexcept`) and [it **must not** be swallowed](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/21541.html). It interacts with `noexcept` as you'd expect: `std::terminate()` is called if a `__forced_unwind` escapes a `noexcept` function, so `noexcept` functions are really `noexcept`, they won't unexpectedly throw some "special" type

Comment: Ah, cancelation points. Now it makes sense. Does linux support asynchronous cancelation and if so then in that case does all that still hold?

Comment: It believe it does support it, but I don't know how or if `__forced_unwind` is involved. My guess would be async cancellation also uses that exception type ... though obviously that is  pretty hard to handle correctly, which is always true of async cancellation

Answer (score 4):

> The problem they are experiencing is that the main thread starts a separate thread to do a potentially long-running TCP connect() [client connecting to server]. If the 'long-running' aspect takes too long, they cancel the thread and start another one.

Trivial fix -- don't cancel the thread. Is it doing any harm? If necessary, have the thread check (when the `connect` finally does complete) whether the connection is still needed and, if not, close it, release the mutex, and terminate. You can do this with a boolean variable protected by a mutex.

Also, a thread should not hold a mutex while waiting for network I/O. Mutexes should be used only for things that are fast and primarily CPU-limited or perhaps limited by local disk.

Finally, if you feel you need to reach in from the outside and force a thread to do something, step back. *You* wrote the code for that thread. If you feel that need, it means you didn't code that thread to do what you really wanted it to do. The fix is to modify the thread to do what, and only what, you actually want. Then you won't have to "push it around" from the outside.

Comment: If it holds the mutex until it eventually times out then it is doing harm (or causing a problem at least) if it prevents a new thread retrying the operation, or some other alternative operation. The best way to avoid that harm is as you say to avoid holding locks across such operations and to not code it that way in the first place. I think I prefer your "then don't do that" answer to my own one.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I agree, -1 for your answer.  (I kid)