# Can std::exception_ptr contain __cxxabi::__forced_unwind?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, pthreads, stdexception-ptr

[On GNU/Linux `pthread_cancel` is implemented with a special exception of type `__cxxabi::__forced_unwind`, so when a thread is cancelled an exception is thrown and the stack is unwound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268080/cancelling-a-thread-that-has-a-mutex-locked-does-not-unlock-the-mutex/14268668#14268668). Therefore, one should always re-throw the exception caught by an `catch (...)`, lest it be `__forced_unwind`, the swallowing of which is met with an angry message from the runtime.

My question is whether it's safe to temporarily pack a `__forced_unwind` via `std::current_exception()` and then `std::rethrow_exception()`, provided I don't swallow it.

In code:

```
~~~
} catch (...) {
    handleException();
}

// elsewhere
void handleException() {
   try { std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception()); }
   catch (const std:exception &e) { log(e.what()); return; } // swallow
   catch (...) { log("unknown exception caught"); throw; } // re-throw, could be __forced_unwind
}
```

Is this well-defined? If so, where is it defined to work?

Comment: No, this is not defined by anything to work. If it works, it's not by design or any explicit choice.

Comment: I shouldn't answer when I'm in a hurry. If it works, it's just because that's how it's implemented and how it works, not because it's explicitly defined anywhere to work. I don't think there's any doc saying exactly how forced unwind is implemented, or guaranteeing that this works. It happens to be a normal refcounted exception (except where it's not, i.e. it can't be swallowed), so this code behaves as expected. But for the question "where is this defined?" I think the answer is that it's not.

Answer (score 1):

It's implementation defined if that'll work. `__cxxabiv1::__forced_unwind` is an abstract type with a private destructor that can only be caught by reference.

```cpp
namespace __cxxabiv1
{
  /**
   *  @brief Thrown as part of forced unwinding.
   *  @ingroup exceptions
   *
   *  A magic placeholder class that can be caught by reference to
   *  recognize forced unwinding.
   */
  class __forced_unwind
  {
    virtual ~__forced_unwind() throw(); // private dtor

    // Prevent catch by value.
    virtual void __pure_dummy() = 0;    // pure
  };
}
```

`std::current_exception` *"captures the current exception object and creates an `std::exception_ptr` that holds either **a copy** or a reference to that exception object (depending on the implementation)."*

If the implementation you use requires a copy, then compilation will fail since it can't be copied. If it does not, it'll just keep a reference to the existing exception object - however for `__forced_unwind`, `std::current_exception()` + `std::rethrow_exception()` will not work. You can rethrow the `__forced_unwind` with `throw;` but `std::current_exception()` will return a null `std::exception_ptr`.

---

Since C++11, `pthread_cancel` has been known to cause the **application** to terminate (but I'm not sure if that's still the case).

Regarding using `pthread_cancel`, Jonathan Wakely wrote (https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00040.html):

> ... or accept that you shouldn't use `pthread_cancel` in C++11. I don't
> have any better suggestions, sorry.

Even if the issues mentioned in that post have been fixed by now, I still think the advice is sound. Don't use `pthread_cancel`, ever! Cancel your threads by setting a state that the thread is checking in places where the thread can terminate in a controlled manner.

Comment: The issues described in your linked post are essentially that a lot of functions, including destructors, are noexcept. Thus application termination is inevitable if you are in one. It might be worth quoting or paraphrasing that here. I believe that issue still exists.

Comment: Also, last time I tested, current_exception returns a null pointer on gcc/Linux, so you cannot save and rethrow.

Comment: @JeffGarrett _"current_exception returns a null pointer"_ - Yes, I made some more digging and realized this and rewrote that part of the answer. I didn't add more from the old post though. I think there are plenty of resources "out there" saying the same thing (don't use `pthread_cancel`) so even if the link would go stale in the future, I don't think it will be hard to find information about _why_.